# Closing an Android app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a simply question. I set up the button which is closing my app:

```
Button turnoffbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
turnoffbutt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

It's working very good, but only when I turn on my app.
When I open another activity by a button

```
startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
```

and then I go back to the menu I can't quit my app (by this button Close). It's getting me to the settingsactivity.
I know that this method (startactivity) is creating a new activity. That's why I can't quit my app.
But how to resolve this problem? May I have to change something on turnoffbutt or use another method to get to the another activity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993889/system-exit0-causes-the-activity-quit-quickly-when-the-app-starts/14993923#comment21102697_14993923

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you should not explicitly "quit" or "close" your app, as that's not how Android is designed.  However if you really want to do something like that, you can just `finish` the activity, something like this:

```
Button turnoffbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
turnoffbutt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

call `finish()` before starting another Activity. That will make your app close when you hit the back button in your SettingsActivity

I suggest you to read [this](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html) article for better understanding the things you are asking about

Comment: Well, the problem is that when I finish each Activity by `finish()`, my app will close with the back button also.

Comment: so what EXACTLY do you need?